# Configuring UART1 in lpc 2468

Tags: arm

I am working on lpc2468 ARM-based microcontroller. I am not able to configure the UART1 of the controller. Previously I was using UART0 for the same purpose, but due to some changes in hardware now I have to use UART1.

I want to connect GPRS module (SIMCOM 300) to the UART1 of the microcontroller. Here's my code so far:

```
void init_serial_gprs (void){
    PINSEL7  |= 0x0000000F;
    U1LCR  = 0x00000080;
    U1DLL  = 0x00000041;
    U1DLM  =   0x00000000;
    U1LCR  = 0x03;
    VICVectAddr7 = (unsigned)serial1_isr;
    VICIntEnable = 1 << 7;
    SBUF= U1RBR;
    U1IER = 3;
}

void serial1_isr(void) __irq {
    volatile char dummy;
    volatile UWORD32 IIR1;

    /*------------------------------------------------
     Repeat while there is at least one interrupt source.
     ------------------------------------------------*/
    while (((IIR1 = U1IIR) & 0x01) == 0)
    {
        switch (IIR1 & 0x0E)
        {
            case 0x06: /* Receive Line Status */
                dummy = U1LSR;  /* Just clear the interrupt source */
                break;

            case 0x04: /* Receive Data Available */
            case 0x0C: /* Character Time-Out */
                SBUF= U1RBR;
                if(genflag.fl_m_psw || new_st == 0 ||new_st == 0x1f){
                    if(genflag.gprs_con)  receive_data();
                    else
                        receive_data_gprs();
                }
                break;

            case 0x02: /* THRE Interrupt */
                if(genflag.gprs_con) transfer_data();
                else transfer_data_gprs();
                dummy   = U1LSR;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    VICVectAddr = 0; /* Acknowledge Interrupt */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try polling the serial port first against a dumb terminal (hyperterm, minicom, putty) to make sure you have the basics then move on to interrupts?

Comment: It looks good, not sure why it isnt working.  is PCLK_SEL0 what you want for the uart?  And your divisors are right?  I would send something out the port and either use a dumb terminal or a scope to make sure the baud rate is what you expect.  Likewise use a dumb terminal back in to see the receiver is working and getting bytes.